# How to load compiled python modules from memory?

Tags: python, module

I need to read all modules (pre-compiled) from a zipfile (built by py2exe compressed) into memory and then load them all.
I know this can be done by loading direct from the zipfile but I need to load them from memory.
Any ideas? (I'm using python 2.5.2 on windows)
TIA Steve

Comment: Can you give some more background? Why do you need to load the code into memory in the first place? Why does loading from a ZIP file not fit?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It depends on what exactly you have as "the module (pre-compiled)".  Let's assume it's exactly the contents of a `.pyc` file, e.g., `ciao.pyc` as built by:

```
$ cat>'ciao.py'
def ciao(): return 'Ciao!' 
$ python -c'import ciao; print ciao.ciao()'
Ciao!
```

IOW, having thus built `ciao.pyc`, say that you now do:

```
$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Feb  6 2009, 19:02:12) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> b = open('ciao.pyc', 'rb').read()
>>> len(b)
200
```

and your goal is to go from that byte string `b` to an importable module `ciao`.  Here's how:

```
>>> import marshal
>>> c = marshal.loads(b[8:])
>>> c
<code object <module> at 0x65188, file "ciao.py", line 1>
```

this is how you get the code object from the `.pyc` binary contents.  **Edit**: if you're curious, the first 8 bytes are a "magic number" and a timestamp -- not needed here (unless you want to sanity-check them and raise exceptions if warranted, but that seems outside the scope of the question; `marshal.loads` will raise anyway if it detects a corrupt string).

Then:

```
>>> import types
>>> m = types.ModuleType('ciao')
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['ciao'] = m
>>> exec c in m.__dict__
```

i.e: make a new module object, install it in `sys.modules`, populate it by executing the code object in its `__dict__`.  **Edit**: the order in which you do the `sys.modules` insertion and `exec` matters if and only if you may have circular imports -- but, this is the order Python's own `import` normally uses, so it's better to mimic it (which has no specific downsides).

You can "make a new module object" in several ways (e.g., from functions in standard library modules such as `new` and `imp`), but "call the type to get an instance" is the normal Python way these days, and the normal place to obtain the type from (unless it has a built-in name or you otherwise have it already handy) is from the standard library module `types`, so that's what I recommend.

Now, finally:

```
>>> import ciao
>>> ciao.ciao()
'Ciao!'
>>>
```

...you can import the module and use its functions, classes, and so on.  Other `import` (and `from`) statements will then find the module as `sys.modules['ciao']`, so you won't need to repeat this sequence of operations (indeed you don't *need* this last `import` statement here if all you want is to ensure the module is available for import from elsewhere -- I'm adding it only to show it works;-).

**Edit**: If you absolutely must import in this way packages and modules therefrom, rather than "plain modules" as I just showed, that's doable, too, but a bit more complicated. As this answer is already pretty long, and I hope you can simplify your life by sticking to plain modules for this purpose, I'm going to shirk that part of the answer;-).

Also note that this may or may not do what you want in cases of "loading the same module from memory multiple times" (this rebuilds the module each time; you might want to check sys.modules and just skip everything if the module's already there) and in particular when such repeated "load from memory" occurs from multiple threads (needing locks -- but, a better architecture is to have a single dedicated thread devoted to performing the task, with other modules communicating with it via a Queue).

Finally, there's no discussion of how to install this functionality as a transparent "import hook" which automagically gets involved in the mechanisms of the `import` statement internals themselves -- that's feasible, too, but not exactly what you're asking about, so here, too, I hope you can simplify your life by doing things the simple way instead, as this answer outlines.

Comment: I was having the same requirement and was looking for a solution, thanks Alex :)

Comment: @S.Mark, no, `.pyc` or `.pyo` only -- `.pyd`s are essentially `.dll`s under a false name and present **completely** different problems.  @Technofreak, you're welcome!-)

Comment: Almost no explanation, a lot of issues are not addressed. This doesn't look like an answer from Alex Martelli :(.

Comment: @Denis, I've edited to add bits and pieces of trivia, but I'm very dubious as to whether this actually enhances the answer.  Yes, there are many more issues (some of which you address, such as the possible need for locking when the same module's imported from multiple threads, and others you don't, such as other repeated imports, packages and dotted-names modules therefrom, etc) -- but, there's a limit to the useful length of a practical answer, and I chose to use space to show details at the interactive prompt rather than for marginalia.

Comment: Thanks for the example and quick reply. I have been using your idea and it works great for modules defined in single files but what should I do for files in packages (__init__ etc) in the zip? I guess this is where it gets a bit complex?

Comment: @Steve, yep, it's one of the things that can make this reasonably simple code more complicated:-(.  What about posting a separate Q specifying what of the various possible complicatons I listed in this A you absolutely _must_ address in your app...?

Comment: Excellent answer my friend.... i know this is necroposting, but man... this has helped me with a problem i had on Google App Engine! Very useful!

Answer (score 10):

Compiled Python file consist of

1. magic number (4 bytes) to determine type and version of Python,
2. timestamp (4 bytes) to check whether we have newer source,
3. marshaled code object.

To load module you have to create module object with `imp.new_module()`, execute unmashaled code in new module's namespace and put it in `sys.modules`. Below in sample implementation:

```
import sys, imp, marshal

def load_compiled_from_memory(name, filename, data, ispackage=False):
    if data[:4]!=imp.get_magic():
        raise ImportError('Bad magic number in %s' % filename)
    # Ignore timestamp in data[4:8]
    code = marshal.loads(data[8:])
    imp.acquire_lock() # Required in threaded applications
    try:
        mod = imp.new_module(name)
        sys.modules[name] = mod # To handle circular and submodule imports 
                                # it should come before exec.
        try:
            mod.__file__ = filename # Is not so important.
            # For package you have to set mod.__path__ here. 
            # Here I handle simple cases only.
            if ispackage:
                mod.__path__ = [name.replace('.', '/')]
            exec code in mod.__dict__
        except:
            del sys.modules[name]
            raise
    finally:
        imp.release_lock()
    return mod
```

**Update**: the code is updated to handle packages properly.

Note that you have to install import hook to handle imports inside loaded modules. One way to do this is adding your finder into [`sys.meta_path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.meta_path). See [PEP302](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/) for more information.