# import hooks (custom module loaders) for pypy do not work

Tags: python, pypy

I'm successfully able to create import hooks to load files directly from memory in python2.7.  The example I used was the accepted response to this question:

[python:Import module from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191900/pythonimport-module-from-memory)

However; when applying this code on pypy; i get an import error.  I have also tried other import hook examples that work with regular python but not with pypy, such as this:

[python load zip with modules from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39135750/python-load-zip-with-modules-from-memory/39136473#39136473)

Does anyone know why import hooks do not work in pypy?  Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in both of the examples you point to, `load_module()` does not add the loaded module to `sys.modules`.  Normally, it should do so (and then PyPy works like CPython).

If `load_module()` does not add the module to `sys.modules`, then every single `import a` will call `load_module()` again and return a new copy of the module.  For example, in the example from [python:Import module from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14191900/pythonimport-module-from-memory):

```
import a as a1
import a as a2
print a1 is a2   # False!
a1.foo = "foo"
print a2.foo     # AttributeError
```

This is documented in https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0302/#id27.  The `load_module()` method is responsible for doing more checks than these simple examples show.  In particular, note this line (emphasis in the original):

> Note that the module object *must* be in sys.modules before the loader executes the module code.

So, the fact that PyPy behaves differently than CPython in this case could be understood as a behavior difference that follows from code that fails to respect the docs.

But anyway, my opinion is that it should be fixed.  I've created an issue at https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2382/sysmeta_path-not-working-like-cpythons.

Comment: Also, note that the two examples you cite don't work in CPython 3.x: they give you an obscure KeyError from somewhere in the internals of ``File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>"``