# run a python file which is stored on amazon s3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a py file stored on amazon s3 bucket, which I read the content as bytes into python runtime(file is not download and saved locally).

This python file has a function. I would like to invoke the function of the py file which stored on amazon s3.

```
def generate(id:str):
   pass
```

Comment: Instead of storing file directly, I would recommend you to serialize (pickle) your class/object and save the same in S3. You should then be able to read pickle file -> deserialize (unpickle) and call the required function. https://realpython.com/python-pickle-module/

Comment: I can't save the serialized. People can edit this file and reupload it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python import from byte IO (or more generally from an object in memory)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175428/python-import-from-byte-io-or-more-generally-from-an-object-in-memory)