# Dynamically import module from memory in Python 3 using Hooks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module

What I want to achieve is exactly what this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14192708/3585576) proposes, however in Python 3.

The code below works fine in Python 2:

```
import sys
import imp

modules = {
"my_module":
"""class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
    def print_number(self):
        print self.x"""}    

class StringImporter(object):

   def __init__(self, modules):
       self._modules = dict(modules)


   def find_module(self, fullname, path):
      if fullname in self._modules.keys():
         return self
      return None

   def load_module(self, fullname):
      if not fullname in self._modules.keys():
         raise ImportError(fullname)

      new_module = imp.new_module(fullname)
      exec self._modules[fullname] in new_module.__dict__
      return new_module


if __name__ == '__main__':
   sys.meta_path.append(StringImporter(modules))

   from my_module import Test
   my_test = Test()
   my_test.print_number() # prints 5
```

However, when making the obvious changes to Python 3 (enclosing exec and print in parentheses) I get the following code:

```
import sys
import imp

modules = {
"my_module":
"""class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 5
    def print_number(self):
        print(self.x)"""}    

class StringImporter(object):

   def __init__(self, modules):
       self._modules = dict(modules)


   def find_module(self, fullname, path):
      if fullname in self._modules.keys():
         return self
      return None

   def load_module(self, fullname):
      if not fullname in self._modules.keys():
         raise ImportError(fullname)

      new_module = imp.new_module(fullname)
      exec(self._modules[fullname])
      return new_module


if __name__ == '__main__':
   sys.meta_path.append(StringImporter(modules))

   from my_module import Test
   my_test = Test()
   my_test.print_number() # Should print 5
```

Not that the `exec()` change was pretty significant. I didn't understand what that line did in Python 2, I "translated" it the way I think it's correct. However, the Python 3 code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 35, in <module>
    from my_module import Test
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 626, in _load_backward_compatible
KeyError: 'my_module'
```

What should I change in the code in order to work in Python 3 the exactly same way it works in Python 2?

Observation: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830727/how-to-load-compiled-python-modules-from-memory) does not answer my question as I'm not interested in importing a module from `.pyc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you forgot to translate the latter half of the `exec` statement from the code sample. That causes the `exec` to be applied `in` the context of the `load_module` method — not the `new_module`; so specify the context:

```
exec(self._modules[fullname], new_module.__dict__)
```

However, using a Python versioned 3.4 or higher, you become subject to [PEP 451](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0451/) (the introduction of [module specs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-module-spec)), as well as the deprecation of the [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html) module, in favor of [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). Particularly:

- The [`imp.new_module(name)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.new_module) function is replaced by `importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)`.
- An abstract base class for meta path finder objects is supplied: `importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder`.
- And such finder objects now use `find_spec` rather than `find_module`.

Here is a very close reimplementation of the code sample.

```
import importlib
import sys
import types


class StringLoader(importlib.abc.Loader):

    def __init__(self, modules):
        self._modules = modules

    def has_module(self, fullname):
        return (fullname in self._modules)

    def create_module(self, spec):
        if self.has_module(spec.name):
            module = types.ModuleType(spec.name)
            exec(self._modules[spec.name], module.__dict__)
            return module

    def exec_module(self, module):
        pass


class StringFinder(importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder):

    def __init__(self, loader):
        self._loader = loader

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path, target=None):
        if self._loader.has_module(fullname):
            return importlib.machinery.ModuleSpec(fullname, self._loader)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    modules = {
        'my_module': """
    BAZ = 42

    class Foo:
        def __init__(self, *args: str):
            self.args = args
        def bar(self):
            return ', '.join(self.args)
    """}

    finder = StringFinder(StringLoader(modules))
    sys.meta_path.append(finder)

    import my_module
    foo = my_module.Foo('Hello', 'World!')
    print(foo.bar())
    print(my_module.BAZ)
```