# How to embed python into a standalone C++ application? (i.e. do not rely on Libs folder on disk)

Tags: python, c++, embed, cpython

I'm trying to embed python into my C++ application, but also make it standalone, i.e. do not rely on python dependencies on a disk, like `Libs` folder with standard library scripts, but still be able to use them. I can find a way to store all the the scripts from `Libs` in the binary by myself and load them into the memory after running the program, but the problem is that I don't know how to "load" them into python interpreter directly from memory, either from text or binary (compiled) scripts, without dropping them on disk, how `pyinstaller` does (it extracts all compiled scripts into temp system dir).

I'm wondering if there is any kind of callback in cpython that allows a user to override `import` keyword and general modules import logic so I could import a module from memory instead of loading it from disk. I couldn't find anything like that on google. Maybe you know if there is such feature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/MarekR22/pycpp_example - did some time ago for other SO question (author has deleted this question).

Comment: @MarekR, it seems like it's not what I want. I want to create a standalone executable like `pyinstaller` does, but without dropping files on disk. In your example it imports a module from disk then calls a function from it, I guess it won't run without preinstalled python because of missing critical files like `os.py`, `encodings/utf8.py`, etc. So I need to somehow make these files importable from memory

Comment: Related: [How to load compiled python modules from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830727/how-to-load-compiled-python-modules-from-memory) and [PEP 302](https://peps.python.org/pep-0302/).

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize a Virtual File System (VFS) to do such thing, You don't need any exe file, Just get python embed version, Configure pip, Link against python310.dll.

Now before calling python dll hook winapi IO function and when python request for your virtual file you feed it back from vfs.

I did it and it worked perfectly. You may want to create a binary archive to stream data from it.