# How to load a module from a byte sequence without saving it to a file in python version 3.11?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyc

My loader receives part of the program from the server as `.pyc` files (the files themselves are NOT saving in client pc's filesystem, the byte sequence is stored in a variable).

I need to create a module from this byte sequence without creating a file.

I found a way to create a module from a string:

```
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader("modulename", loader=None) # creating spec
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec) # creating module
exec(source, module.__dict__) # executing module
#  so that we can import it in other program files
sys.modules[name] = module
globals()[name] = module
```

But it doesn't work for me in my case.

The module is initially created with `py_compile.compile("sorcefile.py", "destfile.pyc")`.
The answer to a similar question ([How to load compiled python modules from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830727/how-to-load-compiled-python-modules-from-memory)) suggests using `marshal.loads(bytes[8:])` and indeed, looking at the source code of `py_compile.compile` function (https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/py_compile.py) I saw that it uses `marshal.dump()`. However, as far as I understand, this code is deprecated, because looking at the source code of this function in my Python instance (3.11) (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/py_compile.py), I saw that it no longer uses marshall.

This explains why this error appears in the following situation:

```
import marshal
import py_compile


py_compile.compile("source.py", "compiled.pyc")
with open("compiled.pyc", "rb") as f:
    module_bytes = f.read()

module = marshal.loads(module_bytes[8:])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    module = marshal.loads(module_bytes[8:])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

(In this case, the pyc file is created only to emulate the data received from the server.)

So, is it possible to create a module from a sequence of bytes without creating a file in python 3.11 (as in the *"string"* method).

Comment: Since marshal expects to read and write NYC files, are you sure your should be skipping those initial bytes?

Comment: @JonSG, The first 8 bytes are the magic number that identifies the python version. The answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830727/how-to-load-compiled-python-modules-from-memory says they are not needed.
Anyway, even with those 8 bytes, the same error appears.